# CRON in Cpanel and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel

I need to perform a scheduled task in CPanel, I know I should use CRON to do the task every day.

I'm using Laravel 7 and PHP version 7.2, I try running task locally on windows and make sure it works, but when I try running using CRON didn't works

I also check that I set the right path of my project

CRON Command is use:

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php /home/my-user/public_html/path-to-project artisan schedule:run  >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Is this on shared hosting? You'll need to check whether the hosting provider allows it. Normally if they do, you can configure the cron job via the cPanel UI. Beyond, that if you want debugging help then we'll need some more detailed information than "didn't work".

Comment: yes it is allowed, I can configure CRON from UI on CPanel.

I'm using it to send saved notification on DB at specific time.
so notification isn't received, and I couldn't now how to debug issue, I set an email to receive emails when CRON is working but I didn't receive any.


@ADyson

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the space in `...path-to-project artisan` to a slash (`...path-to-project/artisan schedule:run`)

Answer (score 0):

You are allow to setup cron using UI on the Cpanel

For that, login into cPanel and go to the Cron Jobs option then create a new cronjob like below.

1 [First Step](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/16103768?key=0808bcd1aa08ac261bd1fc07cbf5b4fc) highlighted

2 [Second Step](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/16103977?key=88288703d25943417c1b740f10ceede3) Change the red-underlined userla with your hosting username.

To test these steps just do the following:

Open the kernel.php file from app/Console directory and define a scheduled task into the schedule method.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

 $schedule->call(function () {

     // your schedule code
     Log::info('Working');
    
 })->everyMinute();
}
```

Check your results  on log

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following way

```
php-path project-path/artisan schedule:run  >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

***OR***

```
cd project-path && php-path artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

In your case

- php-path is `/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php`
- project-path is `/home/my-user/public_html/path-to-project`
- full artisan path is `/home/my-user/public_html/path-to-project/artisan`